# Nginx routing config for multi language

Tags: nginx, config

I have a static website using nginx as server, get some issues when I want to implement multi-lang it.

the final output I want is:

```
mywebsite.dev                     -> get en-US/index.html
mywebsite.dev/about               -> get en-US/about.html
mywebsite.dev/en-US/index.html    -> get en-US/index.html
mywebsite.dev/en-US/about.html    -> get en-US/about.html
mywebsite.dev/js-JP/index.html    -> get js-JP/index.html
```

Instead, I got (which is obvious, but I don't have any clue to solve this)

```
mywebsite.dev                     -> get en-US/index.html
mywebsite.dev/about               -> get 404 not found
mywebsite.dev/en-US/index.html    -> get en-US/index.html
mywebsite.dev/en-US/about.html    -> get en-US/about.html
mywebsite.dev/js-JP/index.html    -> get js-JP/index.html
```

Folder tree:

```
output folder
├── img/
├── js/
├── css/
├── en-US
│     ├── about.html
│     └── index.html
└── js-JP
      ├── about.html
      └── index.html
```

nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.dev www.mywebsite.dev;

    access_log /tmp/mywebsite.access.log;
    error_log /tmp/mywebsite.error.log;

    root /Users/path/to/output/folder;
    index en-US/index.html;

}
```

Is it possible to just modify nginx config to do that?